# Es posible hacer esta consulta en linq?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

```
SELECT CL.ClNIt, CL.ClNombresApe, VS.VsFeha, VS.VsValorNeto, 
VS.VsValorVisita,SUM(CC.CcValor) AS SumCupos, CL.ClSaldoCupo
FROM Visitas VS 
INNER JOIN Clientes CL ON VS.ClNit = CL.ClNIt
INNER JOIN CuposCliente CC ON CL.ClNIt = CC.CcClNit
WHERE CL.ClNIt = 'YMvRBEZ3+aE='
GROUP BY CL.ClNIt, CL.ClNombresApe, VS.VsFeha, VS.VsValorNeto, VS.VsValorVisita , CL.ClSaldoCupo
```

Answer (score 1):

Sería algo así

```
var resultado = from tabla1 in dbo.context1
                join tabla2 in dbo.context2 on tabla1.id == tabla2.id
                join tabla3 in dbo.context3 on tabla2.id ==tabla3.id
group tabla3 by new { tabla1.valor, tabla2.valor } into g
            select new { 
                valor1= g.Key.valor, 
                Valor2= g.Key.Valor, 
                Total = g.Sum(t3 => t3.valor) 
            };
```